# Cannot read property 'roles' of undefined | discord.js | javascript

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

```
bot.on("message", (message) => {
if(message.author.bot) return;
  if(message.content.startsWith(config.prefix + "userinfo") || message.content.startsWith(config.prefix + "ui")) {

    let usera = message.mentions.users.first();
    if(!usera) return message.channel.send("Must specify user");
    let verifiedRole = usera.member.roles.find(val => val.name === 'verified');
    let value = verifiedRole ? "true" : "false";
    let gameName = usera.presence.game ? usera.presence.game.name : "None";


    let embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
    .setAuthor(usera.tag, usera.avatarURL)
    .addField("ID", usera.id, true)
    .addField("Username", usera.username, true)
    .addField("Status", usera.presence.status, true)
    .addField("Game", gameName, true)
    .addField("Joined Server", usera.joinedAt, true)
    .addField("Created", usera.createdAt, true)
    .addField("Bot", usera.bot, true)
    addField("Verified", value, true)
    .setTimestamp()
    .setColor(0x0f7fa6)
    .setThumbnail(usera.avatarURL);
    message.channel.send({embed});

    console.log("'UI' has been executed in the guild '" + message.guild.name + "' by " + message.author.username + " (" + message.author.id + ")");
}
});
```

Running this comes up with 'TypeError: Cannot read property 'roles' of undefined' with an arrow under the word 'roles' in `let verifiedRole = usera.member.roles.find(val => val.name === 'verified');`

How do I fix this?

Comment: It seems as if your `usera` variable is storing a `User` object, which doesn't have the property `members`. It looks like you're trying to work with `Guild`s though, right?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to work with roles, you can not use a `user object`, as the `user object` does not have roles. You need to use [Guild Member](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/GuildMember), which contains the roles property.

To do this, you simply have to change your code to :

```
let usera = message.mentions.members.first();
```

as opposed to `message.mentions.users.first()`.

Edit: Note that this means that for the user part of your code you'll have to put `usera.user...` in order to make it a user object.